# How to access specific element of API Get with Python's Request Package?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, response

Hi I am currently using Python 3.X to run the following code:

```
import requests

jurisdiction = 'us'

name = 'netflix'

limit = 1


r = requests.get('https://opencorporates.com/reconcile?query={%22query%22:%22' + name + '%22,%20%22limit%22:' + str(limit) + ',%20%22jurisdiction_code%22:%22' + jurisdiction + '%22}')

print(type(r))
print(r.text)
```

The output of this is

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>

{"result":[{"id":"/companies/gb/12022722","name":"AMAZON-UK LIMITED","type":[{"id":"/organization/organization","name":"Organization"}],"score":69.0,"match":false,"uri":"https://opencorporates.com/companies/gb/12022722"}],"duration":157.957621}
```

I want to be able to access the company name from the response and then add it to a list. So I can iterate over a bunch of names/jurisdictions and have a list at the end that I can export to csv (or whatever).

I think that using a to.json or json.dump or something like that might work but I am not sure exactly how to do this? I am open to importing more packages like pandas etc, should the need arise.

Comment: Yes, you should use `r.json()` or `json.loads(r.text)` convert the response to Python's dict, then iterate the list and get what you want.

Comment: Hi I did try that and it does give me a dictionary but it comes out like:

`{'result': [{'id': '/companies/gb/12022722', 'name': 'AMAZON-UK LIMITED', 'type': [{'id': '/organization/organization', 'name': 'Organization'}], 'score': 69.0, 'match': False, 'uri': 'https://opencorporates.com/companies/gb/12022722'}], 'duration': 160.53979500000003}`

So the first value for the result key is a list containing a dictionary? Is there no nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import json and you can read the company names like this:-

```
import json

data = json.loads(r.text)

#initialize your list 
namesList = []

for s in data['result']:
    name = s['name']
    namesList.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
data = {"result":[{"id":"/companies/gb/12022722","name":"AMAZON-UK LIMITED","type":[{"id":"/organization/organization","name":"Organization"}],"score":69.0,"match":False,"uri":"https://opencorporates.com/companies/gb/12022722"}],"duration":157.957621}


for i in data['result']:
    print(i['name'])
```